# Rerunning my main function yields different results

Tags: r, list, debugging

I'll get right to the problem. I want my code to do two things:

1. Generate n sets (in this case by using lists) of letters on a screen and save them
   as a png.
2. 50% of n to have a letter from the previous set.

## The Code in question:

```
# This creates the baseline parameters 
memo0 = function(x, y, lett, col="black", cex=3)
{
  text(x, y, lett, col=col, cex=cex)
}


# Creates the list of Letters I will be using
LETTERS_custom = list("B", "C", "D", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "L", "M", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "V", "W", "X", "Z")
# Creates Bolean-Switches for [2]
RGA2 <<- FALSE   
RGA_helper <<- FALSE 

# The main function 
memo_1curr = function (size, prev=NULL, ...)
{
  
}

memo = function(size, prev=NULL, ...)
{
# letter-placer
  step = 0.1
  x = 0.50 + step * 1:size - step*(size+1) / 2
  y = rep(0.50, size)
  if (RGA2 == FALSE) # List-generator #1.
    repeat
    {
      lett = sample(LETTERS_custom, size, replace=TRUE) # Generates a list
      ok = TRUE
      
      if (any(duplicated(lett) %in% c(TRUE))) # Controls for repetition inside the set
        ok = FALSE
      
      if(any(lett %in% prev)) # Controls for repetition with the previous set
        ok = FALSE
      
          
      if(ok)                  # a simple logic-gate that switches between the two list-generators
        RGA_helper <<- TRUE
        print("RGA1") # Debug
        break
    }
  if (RGA2 == TRUE) # List-generator #2
    repeat
    {
      lett = sample(LETTERS_custom, size, replace=TRUE) # Generates a list
      ok = TRUE
      
      lett = lett[-1] # Removes the first (random) item from the list 
      
      if(any(lett %in% prev)) # Controls for repetition with the previous set
        ok = FALSE
      
      s = sample(prev, 1)
      lett = sample(append(lett, s)) # adds random item from the previous set and shuffles the list
      
      if (any(duplicated(lett) %in% c(TRUE))) # Controls for repetition inside the set
        ok = FALSE
      
      
      if(ok)                 # the second part of the logic gate
        RGA2 <<- FALSE
        RGA_helper <<- FALSE
        print("RGA2") # Debug
        break
    }
  if (RGA_helper == TRUE)   # brings the logic gate back
    RGA2 <<- TRUE
  
  memo0(x, y, lett, ...)
  return(lett)
}


# Second part of the letter placer
par(mar=c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1))

plot(NA, NA, xlim=c(0, 1), ylim=c(0, 1), xlab="", ylab="", axes=FALSE)
curr = memo(5)

plot(NA, NA, xlim=c(0, 1), ylim=c(0, 1), xlab="", ylab="", axes=FALSE)
memo(5, prev=curr)
print(curr)

# Generates 10 sets of Letters and saves them into a png.
curr = NULL
for(i in 1:10)
{
    png(sprintf("stim%03i.png", i))
    plot(NA, NA, xlim=c(0, 1), ylim=c(0, 1), xlab="", ylab="", axes=FALSE)
    curr = memo(5, prev=curr)
    dev.off()
}
```

## Remarks

I am quite new to Programming. This code has been mostly written by me - many pieces I likely don't fully understand. I hope the comments are telling. Right now it returns wildly different results along the line of:

```
[1] "RGA1"
[1] "RGA2"
[1] "RGA2"
[1] "RGA1"
[1] "RGA1"
[1] "RGA1"
[1] "RGA1"
[1] "RGA1"
[1] "RGA2"
[1] "RGA1"
```

RG1 is from List-generator #1, RG2 from List-generator #2. My logic gates *should* work swimmingly and I fear the problem might be lying deeper in the way memo() is called in. I am especially stumped by its seemingly random nature. Maybe someone can tip me off in the right direction. Have been working with this particular code all day and can't seem to find the problem.

I am expecting this Debug:

```
[1] "RGA1"
[1] "RGA2"
[1] "RGA1"
[1] "RGA2"
[1] "RGA1"
[1] "RGA2"
[1] "RGA1"
[1] "RGA2"
[1] "RGA1"
[1] "RGA1"
```

Comment: `sample(...)` randomly selects items from its first argument. If you want reproducibility you will use `set.seed` to initialize the RNG.

Comment: I understand the general idea by I am not sure my question was understood properly. I want the main function to randomly pick letters out of LETTERS_custom and I want it to create a pdf with the picked letters. Now I don´t want repetition inside the set and in 50% of the cases I don´t want repetition with the previous set (RG1). The other 50% need to have exactly one letter from the previous set (RG2) - not more and not less. 

My problem is that the program seemingly randomly outputs RG1 and RG2 Algorithms. I am confused to why that is the case.

Comment: If you don’t include a dataset object created using `dput` it’s unlikely that anyone can duplicate your problem. The comment makes it appear that this is really tell distinct problems: 1)selection with some rules that sound vague to me and then 2)  output